# System Restore in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, system-restore, dell-inspiron

Shouldn't the SystemRestore area in the Task Schedule have something listed in it?

System protection is turned on.

This is a Windows 8 system.

Comment: Only (perhaps?) if you've scheduled it.

Comment: Shouldn't the system have scheduled it if it is automated?